# CoreLocations reverseGeocodeLocation getting it to run / loop once per minute only

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, core-location

HiallI am using Corelocation and updating basic long, lat etc to a view as many time per second as possible, this is what I want, but I now have brought in reverseGeocodeLocation  which I only want that to run / geocode the location once per minute. It too at the moment is updating as much as possible which Apple says is bad and only wants it to update once per minute.

Can someone please show me how I do this? (keep my main corelocation updates coming in as much as possible, but have my reverseGeocodeLocation run once per minute.)

I have tried multiple differen ways to limit the amount reverseGeocodeLocation  runlike with a timer, if statements and dispatch_after without success, these other ways I have tried are below, I'm not sure if I need to do something like pause the code somehow while it does the Geocode or ??? etc. My corelocation code is pretty stock standard Apple example code.
Any help would be great!

//code below not showing all code but related parts etc

```
.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
//I set other standard property outlets for location, locationManager, labels etc
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *reverseGeoLastUpdate; //my 60second reversegeoupdates

.m
@implementation ViewController {
NSTimer *timer;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self startStandardUpdates];
}

- (void)startStandardUpdates {
if (nil == _locationManager)
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];

NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow = %f", [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);
if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {
self.coordinateLat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude];
```

//my timer code for reverseGeocodeLocation, trying to get to to run once at the start then every 60 seconds after
//this fires once at the start because self.reverseGeoLastUpdate == nil with no errors but my views onscreen label never actually gets updated with the data from the geoserver, and also the loop does not repeat when [self.reverseGeoLastUpdate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 60???????

```
if( [self.reverseGeoLastUpdate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 60 || self.reverseGeoLastUpdate == nil ){

NSLog(@"Resolving the Address: Loop run %d", _amountofruns++);
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:_location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
        placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
        _address1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@\n",
                          placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                        //other 4 place marker calls here
                          ];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
    }
}];

self.reverseGeoLastUpdate = [NSDate date];
}
}
```

When I tried a NSTimer in place of where the "//my timer" code is in the method above but get

"Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed".

```
NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0
                             target: self
                           selector:@selector(onTick:)
                           userInfo: nil
                            repeats:YES];

-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:_location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
    placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
    _address1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@\n",
                      placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                        //other 4 place marker calls here

                      ];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
}
}];
```

When I tried 
dispatch_after way it fires and label gets updated but once it fires it continuously fires every frame, and couldn't work out how to get it to go once per 60 seconds.

```
double delayInSeconds = 60.0;
dispatch_time_t delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
           ^(void){

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
    placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
    _address1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@\n",
                        placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                        //other 4 placemarks
                        ];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
}
}];

});
```

Any help with figuring out how to do this properly would be great

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is almost correct, but you need to account for the fact that the reverse geocode will complete on a background thread and that you should only update the UI on the main queue.

```
if(self.reverseGeoLastUpdate == nil || [self.reverseGeoLastUpdate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 59 ) {
    self.reverseGeoLastUpdate = [NSDate date];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.address1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@\n",
                          placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                        //other 4 place marker calls here
                          ];
               });
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }

    }];
    }
}
```

Also, try to get out the habit of using _ instead of `self` to access properties unless you deliberately want to bypass a setter/getter

Comment: Hi Paulw11 thanks for the reply yeah I haven't delved into having things run on different threads yet. When I execute your code (I added debug 4 timeInterval) I now get 
2014-12-18 12:28:16.028 myapp[16858:10068748] self.reverseGeoLastUpdate timeIntervalSinceNow 0.000000

2014-12-18 12:28:16.207 myapp[16858:10068748] Found placemarks: (null), error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)"

2014-12-18 12:28:16.207 myapp[16858:10068748] Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)"
?

Comment: also you might be able to tell me what does the [16858:10068748] mean in my debug console outputs?

Comment: I don't know what the numbers mean. I presume it is something to do with the process id and date/time.  The reason for the error 8 is because the location you tried to reverse geocode is nil. In your original code you use `_location`, which I changed to `self.location` but your code above that doesn't set `self.location`/`_location` it sets the local variable `location`.  I have updated my answer to remove `self.`